# PHP queries sending data to SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to know if there is any added information to a php query.

For example, if I use

```
INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
    VALUES ('Glenn', 'Quagmire',33)
```

will there be any added information other than `FirstName`, `LastName` and `Age`, such as a timestamp or a log, stored anywhere in the database, on the server or on the user's computer?

If so, how can I get rid of this using PHP only.

Comment: There's likely to be some logging in place on the server, which may include timestamps, IP addresses, referrers and other information. If you don't own the server, that's completely out of your control.  Also outside your control is what the end user's client browser does to store form fields.

Comment: Also, the database may have triggers or field defaults which set timestamps or other information. Again, if it isn't your database, that is out of your control. (but PHP only executes what you instruct it to - _PHP itself_ won't add anything else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is **no**. This is pure SQL query to database. And it only does what you type and it only affects those three columns in the table `Persons`.

But if you're asking about database log or anything.... well, it depends on database, but I think database adds some meta information to the queries (because it needs to be persistant and [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)). But you don't have to be afraid of that. It's not human readable.

So just use it as it is. PHP itselt does not add anything else to the query neither do database.

Comment: Not true in some cases. There's special TIMESTAMP type column, that gets updated whenever any other value in the row is changed. Also update can trigger UPDATE triggers.